# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_docs' has no attribute 'plots'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I get some errors when I run the code in [this tutorial by Google](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#small_model). 
when I run the following piece of code:

```
plotter = tfdocs.plots.HistoryPlotter(metric = 'binary_crossentropy', smoothing_std=10)
plotter.plot(size_histories)
plt.ylim([0.5, 0.7])
```

It gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_docs' has no attribute 'plots'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs

import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs

import tensorflow_docs.plots
```

This worked for me when I had the same problem :)